# Blender Render Image not showing nothing

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I tried to render a frame in my scene and didnt show anything. I did that already but now suddenly this doesnt work!Im trying to render the frame in evee
Can you help me?
[image]

Comment: Can you upload a .blend and share it here? Or take a screenshot of your scene and render settings before you hit render?

Comment: Hello! https://drive.google.com/file/d/1n8vvUx6wUNO5sN4YjTmzlsVJJ2Y5dCdx/view?usp=sharing  I sent the google drive link, you need to request access :)

Comment: Requested access. Next time you upload a blend file here, use blend-exchange:  https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Sorry I didnt know about that! I sent you an email :)

Comment: Hi, please use [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) for uploading blend files (you may [edit your question](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)  to add a file). Using other sites, especially requiring users to request access only inhibits people from helping you. Thanks.

Comment: Im new on blender and blender forums. I didnt know about that! I need to delete the comment?

Comment: Check my answer, this solved the problem for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my object not show up?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up)

Comment: Yes susu. The topic 9 is the solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me. Disable the "Sequencer" checkbox in Output Properties:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Im new on blender, and before I used that to try the animation render! Thank you! Solved Problem :)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!